# How are variables added to tf.trainable_variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I read this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/) on how to make a quick neural net with TensorFlow, and it works great.

But, I wanted to understand more about how it worked.

In the code, we define the neural net with:

```
def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl0, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output
```

and then eventually run

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
```

I want to figure out how AdamOptimizer knows what matricies to change, since none of them are passed into the minimize function.

So, I looked up [AdamOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize) and found out that `minimize` has an optional parameter:

```
var_list: Optional list or tuple of Variable objects to update to minimize loss. Defaults to the list of variables collected in the graph under the key GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES.
```

So I then looked up [GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) and found:

```
When passed trainable=True, the Variable() constructor automatically adds new variables to the graph collection GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES. This convenience function returns the contents of that collection.
```

So I then did a search for the term `trainable` in my code and found nothing.

So how in the world does the AdamOptimizer know what it should change to optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trainable` argument is passed to the `Variable` constructor, and implicitly defaults to true. Set it to false in your code to avoid training on some variables.